# Video width must be divisible by 8

Tags: c#, winforms, size, aspect-ratio

I have a form that captures all screens from two monitors, but I keep getting a message "Video width must be divisible by 8." when I run this code from a secondary Thread and when the screen size is:

1366w x 768h on the second monitor.

If I run this code on the primary Thread it works, not sure if this matters, but still I can't figure out how it knows it's "Video". I've tried to round up the values, but still won't do it, I know the issue is in the code somewhere, but can someone please tell if there is a way to prevent this from happening?

This code returns the maxwidth and maxheight of all screens.

```
                int noofscreens = 0;
                Screen[] allScreens;
                allScreens = Screen.AllScreens;
                noofscreens = allScreens.Length;

                int maxwidth = 0, maxheight = 0;
                int boundValueX = 0, boundValueY = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < noofscreens; i++)
                {
                    // WIDTH
                    if (allScreens[i].Bounds.X >= 0)
                    {
                        if (maxwidth < (allScreens[i].Bounds.X + allScreens[i].Bounds.Width)) maxwidth = allScreens[i].Bounds.X + allScreens[i].Bounds.Width;
                    }
                    else if (allScreens[i].Bounds.X < 0)
                    {
                        maxwidth = maxwidth + allScreens[i].Bounds.X;
                        boundValueX = allScreens[i].Bounds.X;
                    }
                    // HEIGHT
                    if (allScreens[i].Bounds.Y >= 0)
                    {
                        if (maxheight < (allScreens[i].Bounds.Y + allScreens[i].Bounds.Height)) maxheight = allScreens[i].Bounds.Y + allScreens[i].Bounds.Height;
                    }
                    else if (allScreens[i].Bounds.Y < 0)
                    {
                        maxheight = maxheight + allScreens[i].Bounds.Y;
                        boundValueY = allScreens[i].Bounds.Y;
                    }
                }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well we need some more information as to what library or code you are using that is generating the must be divisible by 8. 1366 isn't divisible by 8 without a remainder.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the solution by rounding up the values.